# Constructing a CPTP-map on one density matrix using another

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra, density-operator

**My question is**: If one is given two density matrices $A$ and $B$, is there a way to use the first to construct a CPTP-map (quantum channel) acting on the on the other?

I thought that Stinespring factorization theorem would allow me to do this by writing

> $\Phi_A(B) := A^\dagger*B*A$

where * is the usual matrix multiplication. However when I used this in Qutip I realised that in fact this leads to a matrix with a trace other than 1, and so this can't be a representation of a density operator. Clearly I have misunderstood the theorem.

An explanation of my error would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to point out your mistake: What you do just doesn't make sense. Stinespring relates CPTP maps to (i) unitaries and (ii) on bigger systems (with an ancilla attached).  You have neither of this.

If you want to use a density matrix to construct a map, you can use the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism.  Given a d-level system and a quantum state $\sigma$ on $d\times d$ level system, this allows you to construct a CP map on the original system.  If one of the reduced density matrices of the state is maximally mixed, the map is in addition trace preserving.

Comment: Thanks for the help - as it happened I found myself using the Choi-Jamiolkowski - I think the mistake was lead to by a misunderstanding I had regarding c* algebras where, like you suggest, I should have actually been looking at the larger tensor space.